# How to hide/remove search box from sensenet homepage for Visitors (before login)

Tags: sensenet

I want to remove search box for Visitor users on the homepage of my custom sensenet site. I want to display it only after a user is logged in to the site. I tried to achieve this with making changes in the skin.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following to the end of pagetemplate html's body

```
<snpe:ClientContextPortlet runat="server" id="ClientContext" />
```

This will add context information in json to the html of the page, and you'll be able to check if the current user is loggedin or not (in this case she's name is Visitor).
Then add the following to the init.js (/Root/Skins/sensenet/scripts/init.js)

```
$(function(){
  if(SN.Context.currentUser.name === "Visitor")
    $('.sn-quicksearch').hide();
  else
    $('.sn-quicksearch').show();
})
```

Comment: in file system i added    $(function () {
        if (SN.Context.currentUser.name === "Visitor")
            $('.sn-quicksearch-text').hide();
        else
            $('.sn-quicksearch-text').show();
    })  after    SN.Util.InitSubmitButtonDisable();  in init.js) and <snpe:ClientContextPortlet runat="server" id="ClientContext" /> added after end of pagetemplate.html body. I also do same in content explore but i added <snpe:ClientContextPortlet runat="server" id="ClientContext" /> in sn-layout-login.html still search box is appearing  before login

Comment: If you want to hide it on the mainpage you have to place it to the mainpage's pagetemplate (sn-layout-inter-index.html) and not into sn-layout-login

Comment: Hello it works but it hide only search box and it shows  working search logo

Comment: done. Thanks. I also want to displays my site page after login.It means admin/user should land on (Root/Profiles/BuiltIn/Admin) after login

Comment: there's a wiki article about this, check it out: http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_build_a_custom_main_page_for_identified_users